# Pyramid framework functional testing with template context

Tags: pyramid, functional-testing, webtest

I have written several functional tests for Pyramid framework application. The HTML response is generated using webtest. Then the test would assert whether a string exists in the body or does not.

Additionally I would like to inspect the global variables. Since Pyramid does not use "template context" anymore, my views and mako templates rely on the request.context.

However I don't know how to access them during a functional test using the webtest library.
Does anyone know how to access request.context or even "template context" during functional testing?

Here are some quotes relevant to this topic.

"In addition to the methods on the self.app() object, Pylons also gives you access to some of the Pylons globals that have been created during the request."

"The Pyramid structure has three major benefits:
1(...), 2( It's simpler and more modular. No magic globals ), 3(...)"

Answer (score 0):

It is not documented in the Pyramid docs. Maybe their desire is to kill this feature once and for all.

```
import pyramid
dir(pyramid.request)
```

You will now see the documented and probably preferred 'Request' and the legacy 'TemplateContext'.

Import it in your controller or unit test files as usual to get it working or in your main configuration file.